# Rename variable names in stargazer latex table

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I have made this model selection table:

```
lm_mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ drat + hp + wt, mtcars)

library(MuMIn)
mod_sel_lm_mtcars <- (mod.sel(lm_mtcars))

mod_sel_lm_mtcars

Model selection table 
          (Intrc)  drat       hp     wt df  logLik AICc delta weight
lm_mtcars   29.39 1.615 -0.03223 -3.228  5 -73.366  159     0      1
```

I can get `stargazer` to convert it to a latex table:

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(mod_sel_lm_mtcars)
```

How can I get `stargazer` to print variable names as in [Coulombe Et Al 2011, p288, Table 2](http://quinnkesler.net/storage/publications/AukTuamotuKF2011.pdf).

Therefore:

1. df should be renamed to k (in italics)
2. delta should be renamed to [latex symbol \Delta] AICc
3. weight should be renamed to w[subscript i]

Comment: Try just replacing the colnames using `names(mod_sel_lm_mtcars)[c(5,8,9)] <- c('\\emph{k}','$\\delta$ AICc','$w_i$')`. The result seems to cause `stargazer` to error; but its output is not what you want anyway since it's running summary on the dataframe. Try just using `xtable::xtable(mod_sel_lm_mtcars)`, which gets you close. `stargazer` is great for models, but not for dataframes, which is the type of object you have here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the covariate.labels argument. for this (As you didn't make clear which rows you wanted to keep in the output, I assumed you wanted them all, but you can change that as well using the keep argument.)

```
stargazer(mod_sel_lm_mtcars, 
      covariate.labels = 
        c("(Intercept)", "drat", "hp", "$w_{i}$",
          "\\textit{k}", "logLik", "AICc", "\\Delta AICc"))
```